# UpdatePanel not updating until after function has completed

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Button ID="btnBackup" runat="server" Text="Backup" 
            onclick="btnBackup_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The idea is that when the user clicks on the button, it is disabled, a function is called, and then at the end of the function the button is enabled again:

```
protected void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnBackup.Enabled = false;
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
    doSomething();
}
```

However, the button is not disabled until after doSomething() has completed.  If I comment out doSomething(), then the button is instantly disabled when I click it.

Is there a way to disable the button before the function call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClientClick propery

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBackup" runat="server" Text="Backup"  OnClientClick = "this.disabled = true;" onclick="btnBackup_Click" />
```

Comment: The onclick event does not fire if I add a OnClientClick

Answer (score 0):

One of two things are needed:

- Define the triggers for the UpdatePanel
- Set the button to AutoPostback

Comment: It's not possible to set the AutoPostback property of an asp:Button

Comment: Did you try setting the trigger? Or the property that has child elements trigger the UpdatePanel?